# Module to create nodes that are lists of other nodes?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm looking for a way to allow users on my site create a piece of content that is a list of current content. For example a user can create a "favorite articles list" content piece and then select his favorite existing articles that will populate this new content type. 
Is there an exisiing module that does this or something similar?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to create a node which has allows for the selection of node that has a field to select other nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. It doesn't create nodes, but the idea is pretty much what you're lining out.

> Flag is a flexible flagging system that is completely customizable by the administrator. Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of entity. Some possibilities include bookmarks, marking important, friends, or flag as offensive. With extensive views integration, you can create custom lists of popular content or keep tabs on important content.
>
> Flags may be per-user, meaning that each user can mark an item individually, or global, meaning that the item is either marked or it is not marked, and any user who changes that changes it for everyone.

Comment: Then you should take a look at References (former Node reference) or Entity Reference. Both allow you to create references to other nodes from a node. 

https://www.drupal.org/project/references, 
https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are look for the [Views Module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

> You need Views if
>
> You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it
>   differently. You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you
>   want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically. You use
>   /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type. You
>   like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles
>   the way you like. You want a way to display a block with the 5 most
>   recent posts of some particular type. You want to provide 'unread
>   forum posts'. You want a monthly archive similar to the typical
>   Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the
>   form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month,
>   and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>   for that month. Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some
>   of the obvious uses of Views.

Despite that terrible description from the module page, Views is a sql query manager that arranges data however you like. It allows you to very specifically create lists of all types of entities (users, nodes, taxonomy, etc) and customise the layout and information presented to users. The front page here on Drupal Answers for example can easily be duplicated using Views.

Answer (score 0):

The [Relation Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/relation_add) Module was the solution. It allowed me to  add me to set a list of related nodes to another node via a custom field.